# How to replace only last two sign to nothing using method Replace

Tags: c#, replace

I've got string `"55, 55,55, 55, "` and I want to replace last two characters (comma and white space) to nothing using only the method `.Replace()`. The example below clear all commas but I want to clear only two last ones. In Java you write:

```java
variable.replaceAll(", $","");  // it's correct effect two last characters are changed to nothing
```

```cs
Replace(", ","") // but in c# you get: 55555,5555 and Replace(", $","") doesn't work
```

How to write it properly to get this effect using only `Replace` method?

Comment: In C# we'd `TrimEnd(' ',',')` rather than busting out Regex for something as trivial as that... Could also `str[..^2]` if you know it's always 2 chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_):

```cs
Regex.Replace(input, ", $", "");
```

If it is always two characters, you could also combine `String.EndsWith` and `String.Substring`, which is likely cheaper than compiling and applying a regex:

```cs
if (input.EndsWith(", ")) {
  input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 2);
}
```